# "cvxpy" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, cvxpy

python==3.11.3
Macbook M1
I have successfully downloaded the module 'cvxpy', and I can import it in the terminal, but every time I try to import it in VsCode, it always tells 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvxpy'. I am very sure I have downloaded it, and it also shows that '"cvxpy" is not accessed Pylance', how can I deal with this problem???

successfully import the module 'cvxpy' in VsCode

Answer (score 1):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvxpy'

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` --> Select the correct interpreter (*the python environment where cvxoy is installed*).

[image]

The lower right corner displays the python version being used in the current workspace, and you can also click it to switch

[image]

---

> "cvxpy" is not accessed Pylance

This warning means that you are not using `cvxpy` yet, this is not an error. If you use `cvxpy` in subsequent code, the warning will disappear.

[image]

[image]

*You can see it's shades change. There is also `Import "cvxpy" could not be resolved` errors because I don't have `cvxpy` installed.*